# CSS: Overflow: hidden and translate X masks the rest of the sentence and just moves the letters over everything on its left

Tags: css, css-animations, css-grid

I'm looking to have the album name and title from a song appear somewhere on an app I'm currently building, but I'm having trouble making it scroll automatically when the length exceeds the room in the container. The best way I can describe the expected result would be to have the first letters disappear and the rest of the string appear as it is moving to the left, like when you have the name of a song in a car radio but the screen doesn't have enough room to show the whole thing. This first image is what it looks like [without animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LliFL.png). As you can see, the overflow is hidden but the start of the title is in the right place.

Then, if I start the animation, [this is what it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN0kv.png). The overflow is still hidden, instead of hiding the first part of the title, and it's moving into the "Title:" part, which is not at all what I want.

Here is my react component/html:

```
<div className="track-info">
    <div style={{textAlign: 'right', gridColumnStart: '1', gridRowStart: '1'}}>
        Album: 
    </div>

    <div className="scrolling-album-container" >
        <span className="scrolling-album">
            {track.selectedTrack?.album.name}
        </span>
    </div>

    <div style={{textAlign: 'right', gridColumnStart: '1', gridRowStart: '2'}}>
        Title: 
    </div>

    <div className="scrolling-title-container" >
       <span className="scrolling-title" >
            {track.selectedTrack?.name}
       </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.track-info {
    font-size: $font-size-xl;
    place-self: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    column-gap: 1rem;

    > * {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }    
}

.scrolling-album-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.scrolling-album {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

.scrolling-title-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
}

.scrolling-title {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    animation: scrollText 10s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes scrollText {
    to {
        transform: translateX(-66.6666%);
    }
}
```

I know I am missing something because there are a million ways to do this that I have found on the web and so far I've been trying to copy them with no luck. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
So I just tried adding a

tag to the text, and making the animation apply to .scrolling-title > p (all child elements of .scrolling-title) but the rest is still hidden.

HTML:

```
<div className="scrolling-title-container" >
      <span className="scrolling-title" >
            <p>{track.selectedTrack?.name}</p>
      </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrolling-title-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrolling-title {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;    
}
.scrolling-title > p {
    animation: 10s linear infinite scrollText;
}
```

Comment: This `> * {` is not valid CSS!

Comment: No this actually is correct. Please search selecting all the children css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo should be moving the overflow: hidden to `.scrolling-title-container`. By putting it in `.scrolling-title`, your basically moving the box and saying nothing should go out of the box, which is redundant. But when the parent box has overflow: hidden, your saying the child can move but it cant go out of the parents box.

```css
 .scrolling-title-container {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

  .scrolling-title {
      position: absolute;
      max-width: 100%;
  }

   .animation {
      animation: scrollText 10s infinite linear;
   }
```

```html
<div className="scrolling-title-container" >
       <div className="scrolling-title" >
          <div className="animation">  {track.selectedTrack?.name} </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for moving the letters, but the rest of the sentence does not show... any ideas?

Comment: @FrancoisBelanger Could clarify on that more. With images maybe and what do you want it to be looking like?

Comment: Let's say the title of the song is 20 letters long. The container/child show the first 10 letters and then when the animation begins, those 10 first letters shift to the left, but the other 10 letters are not showing. (I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to insert images in comments)

Comment: No worries I got your picture. So make sure the box of text is not moving entirely instead of the texts themselves. You can see that by dev tools.

Comment: It's the box that is moving, indeed. How would I make the text move instead?

Comment: Give the animation to the text itself. Ill try to see if I can add that to the code while your doing it.

Comment: So I just tried adding a <p> tag to the text, and making the animation apply to .scrolling-title > p (all child elements of .scrolling-title) but the rest is still hidden.

HTML:
<div className="scrolling-title-container" >
      <span className="scrolling-title" >
            <p>{track.selectedTrack?.name}</p>
      </span>
</div>

CSS:
.scrolling-title-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.scrolling-title {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;    
}
.scrolling-title > p {
    animation: 10s linear infinite scrollText;
}

Comment: @FrancoisBelanger Yeah thats basically it. Try my code.

Comment: Oh and try not to put <p> inside <span>. If its not text as a first child, go for <div>.

Comment: @FrancoisBelanger I learned myself something new. Replace the p tag or span tag with div.